# Colon, Semicolon, or Em-dash

Tags: semicolons, colons, em-dashes

Which of the following three are correct?

1. I would recommend reading the footnotes wherever indicated: they're quite informative.
2. I would recommend reading the footnotes wherever indicated; they're quite informative.
3. I would recommend reading the footnotes wherever indicated -- they're quite informative.